# Checking Functions exist on FunctionApp in Azure via DevOps Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

On Azure DevOps I have a build/deploy YAML pipeline which builds my Function App and deploys this to a Linux Function App in Azure (hosted on an app-service plan).

However, recently I noticed an issue where the pipeline was showing the function app was successfully deployed, but when going into the FunctionApp in Azure and clicking on the Functions tab on the left, it shows "No results", but there should be 4 functions in there.

I want to have a step at the end of the deploy pipeline which checks that 4 functions exist in this FunctionApp, and to fail the pipeline run if this is not the case.

I know this will most likely be a task in the pipeline using Azure CLI or Powershell, but not sure how I would go around writing the script. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Azure CLI task and call the Rest API to list the functions withint the FunctionApp. I don't think the native Az CLI and Azure PowerShell functions expose the functions within the FunctionApp/

```bash
URI = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<functionAppName>/functions?api-version=2015-08-01"

az rest -u $URI --method get | jq '.value[].name'
```

Comment: So would the task in the pipeline look like this?
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <SubscriptionInfo>
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: 'scripts/check-functions.sh'

Then in check-functions.sh I would have the code block you provided but with my details in the URI?

Comment: I haven't tested this and without the rest of the pipeline for context etc this should give you enough to go off: https://gist.github.com/brettmillerb/7a364d764e1f6c0e8917ece1c03d89bb.

Comment: Had to change it a little but that seems to have done the job, thank you so much Brett!

Answer (score 0):

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   #get token
   $TENANTID="xxx"
   $APPID="xxx"
   $PASSWORD="xxx"
   $result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
   $token=$result.access_token
   
   ##set Header
   $Headers=@{
       'authorization'="Bearer $token"
       'host'="management.azure.com"
   }
   
   $functions = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subcription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function app name>/functions?api-version=2015-08-01"  -Headers $Headers -ContentType "application/json" -Method GET
   
   
   if($functions.value.Count -eq 4) {
       # make pipeline to succeed
       Write-Host 'Function deployment success.'
       exit 0
   }
   else {
       Write-Host 'Function deployment failed.'
       exit 1
   }
   
   
  displayName: 'Check whether the function app deployment completed.'
```

If you have concerns, let me know.